# Reading and writing with Entity Framework Core without spontaneous changes of entity objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, deep-copy, entity-framework-core-2.1

EF Core modifies objects it tracks by setting keys and maintaining navigation properties.

As an example of why this may be a problem, let's say you start a task which will add an entity to a DbContext. If you then immediately enumerate some navigation properties of that same entity without waiting for the task to finish, you can get an `InvalidOperationException`. When the entity got tracked in the other thread, it might have picked up some other data from the context and changed the collection.

I'd like to avoid those issues by cloning the entities going into and out of EF Core. But I also don't wish to write a ton of unmaintainable and error-prone code for cloning the entities by hand.

Here's how far I got:

```
public static TEntity CloneEntity<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : class
{
    if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

    // A map for keeping track of already-cloned objects for circular references.
    var map = new Dictionary<object, object>(ReferenceEqualityComparer.Instance);

    return (TEntity)Recurse(context.Entry(entity));


    object Recurse(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        if (map.TryGetValue(entry.Entity, out var clone))
            return clone;

        clone = entry.CurrentValues.ToObject();
        map.Add(entry.Entity, clone);

        // TODO: Recursively clone and set all the navigation properties.

        return clone;
    }
}
```

I can probably figure out how to solve the TODO-bit by reflection, but EF Core should have done all of that already and it should already have compiled methods for efficiently setting navigation properties. Is there a way to use those, similar to `entry.CurrentValues.ToObject()`?

Comment: "you can get an InvalidOperationException. When the entity got tracked in the other thread" You can't use a DbContext concurrently from multiple threads to begin with.  And you can always query an Entity with no tracking, so the Change Tracker doesn't track it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: @David I didn't say anything about using DbContext from multiple threads simultaneously. And I know about AsNoTracking, but it only solves a part of the problem. I'd still like to be able to write things into the database without modifying the input. And I'd like to do a read-modify-write and return the original data without a double query.

Comment: Can you clarify "When the entity got tracked in the other thread,"
It might help on elaborating on the exact problem you are facing rather than the problem with the solution you believe you need for the original problem. It's quite possible that there is an assumption in your desired implementation that can be easily corrected for without needing to worry about cloning new entities to avoid an exception.

Comment: I must agree with @StevePy. I have been thinking about scenario which will need cloned entities and couldn't find any. It may exist, but it will be very helpful to give more context to your problem.

Comment: @Steve You schedule a task on a thread pool. That will be executed on another thread. The task starts a context, adds the entity you provided. As it does that, it modifies the collection inside the entity object. You are simultaneously enumerating the collection on your own thread and you get an exception because it got changed. (It's even worse because it's UB, not a simple exception.)

Comment: @dropout You have five child entities all referencing a single parent. You define the relationships by just setting the children's reference navigation properties to the common parent. When you add those five objects to the context, all of their parent id properties will get modified. Also, the parent's collection navigation property will be set to reference the five children. If you were doing something with the entities in a different thread at the same time (for instance, serializing them), you now have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Of course there are ways around this being a problem. The obvious ones are to 1) serialize data access or 2) use different classes to represent the data outside EF. 1) limits your options and 2) is equivalent to what I'm trying to do anyway: it just makes everything safe by copying.

Comment: @random - Yeah, no.. You need to avoid an approach that takes an entity, hands it off to another thread to process against a DbContext. As soon as the entity is associated to a context in a worker thread that reference should not be used from the original (or any other) thread. Entities reflect data state. If your worker thread manages data state then it should work solely with the entities and your main thread should work with view models. Libraries like Automapper can handle transforming and transferring between entitiy and view model and back as needed.

Comment: @Steve You have rephrased the things I already said. The reason you should avoid the approach and use view models (I mentioned this as alternative 2) is because EF changes the entities. I'd also like to try and avoid the need for extra classes, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: have you tried using AutoMapper to clone entities? It's very easy to use

Comment: @relatively_random: Thanks for the use case. I am trying something. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @relatively_random: I guess not perfect solution, but working one.

Comment: @Licentia Tried it quickly today, it felt like hacking was required to make it work. See author's comments on https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/340 and https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/405.

Answer (score 1):

As far as you are able to deliver solution by your own(I guess) I just put in here something I spent time on. It is a working draft. It may or may not satisfy your needs and may help others to find at least something as a solution.

I like expresions, so it was done using them, but still you can go purely with reflection.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Create data

        using (var context = new ConsoleDbContext())
        {
            context.Add(new Person()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Relatively Random",
                Animals = new List<Animal>
                    {
                        new Cat {Id= 1, Name = "Relatively" },
                        new Dog {Id = 2, Name = "Random" }
                    },
                Address = new Address
                {
                    Street = "Sesame street",
                    City = "London",
                    Country = "United Kingdom"
                }
            }).State = EntityState.Added;

            context.Add(new Person()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Random Relatively",
                Animals = new List<Animal>
                    {
                        new Cat {Id= 3, Name = "Relatively" },
                        new Dog {Id = 4, Name = "Random" }
                    }
            });

            #endregion

            #region Save data

            context.SaveChanges();

            #endregion

            // Create empty clone map
            IDictionary<EntityEntry, object> cloneMap = new Dictionary<EntityEntry, object>(context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count());

            Func<Dog> getDogFunc = () => context.Set<Dog>().Last();

            // Get entry we want to clone
            var dog = context.Entry(getDogFunc());

            // Clone entry
            Dog dogClone = CloneEntity<Dog>(dog, cloneMap);

            // Change name of tracked entity
            dog.Entity.Name = "New name";

            // Compare against entity entry entity value and entity itself(which is non sense as those are same reference, but just to be sure it works
            var result = (dogClone.Name == dog.Entity.Name) || (dogClone.Name == getDogFunc().Name);
        }
    }

    public static TEntity CloneEntity<TEntity>(EntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<EntityEntry, object> cloneMap)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        if (entityEntry == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entityEntry));
        }

        if (cloneMap is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cloneMap));
        }

        //Try get existing clone
        if (cloneMap.TryGetValue(entityEntry, out var clone))
        {
            return (TEntity)clone;
        }

        var cloneMapConstant = Expression.Constant(cloneMap);
        var entityEntryType = typeof(EntityEntry);
        var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>(typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Length);
        var entryParameter = Expression.Parameter(entityEntryType, "entry");

        // Create property binding expressions e.g. Name = entry.Entity.Name
        bindings.AddRange(CreatePropertyBinding<TEntity>(ref entityEntry, ref entryParameter));
        // Create reference binding expression e.g. Owner = new Owner() { ..initialization... }
        bindings.AddRange(CreateReferenceBinding(entityEntry, cloneMapConstant));

        // Get existing clone or create new one based on binding expressions created earlier 
        var result = GetOrCreateNewEntity<TEntity>(ref entityEntry, ref entryParameter, ref bindings);

        cloneMap.Add(entityEntry, result);

        return result;
    }

    private static TEntity GetOrCreateNewEntity<TEntity>(ref EntityEntry entityEntry, ref ParameterExpression entryParameter, ref List<MemberBinding> bindings)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        // new TEntity()
        var newEntity = Expression.New(typeof(TEntity));

        // new TEntity() { ...initialization...  }
        var initilizer = Expression.MemberInit(newEntity, bindings);

        // entry => new TEntity() { ...initialization...  }
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(initilizer, entryParameter);

        // Compile expression to function
        var function = lambda.Compile();

        // Invoke function and cast result
        var result = (TEntity)function.DynamicInvoke(entityEntry);

        // Return result
        return result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MemberBinding> CreateCollectionBinding(EntityEntry entityEntry, ConstantExpression cloneMapConstant)
    {
        // Get all collection properties
        var collections = entityEntry
            .Collections;
        //.Where(n => n.IsLoaded);

        var cloneEntityMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(CloneEntity));

        foreach (var collection in collections)
        {
            // ICollection<SomeType>
            var clrType = collection.Metadata.ClrType;

            var elementType = clrType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

            var hashSetType = typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

            // new HashSet<SomeType>()
            var hashSet = Expression.New(hashSetType);

            var converted = Expression.TypeAs(hashSet, clrType);

            var result = Expression.Bind(collection.Metadata.PropertyInfo, converted);

            yield return result;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<EntityEntry> GetCollectionItemEntries(DbContext context, CollectionEntry collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection.CurrentValue)
        {
            yield return context.Entry(item);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MemberBinding> CreateReferenceBinding(EntityEntry entityEntry, ConstantExpression cloneMapConstant)
    {
        var references = entityEntry
            .References
            .Where(n => n.IsLoaded);

        var result = new List<MemberBinding>(references.Count());

        var cloneEntityMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(CloneEntity));

        foreach (var reference in references)
        {
            var referenceEntityEntry = Expression.Constant(reference.EntityEntry.Context.Entry(reference.TargetEntry.Entity));

            var genericCloneEntityMethod = cloneEntityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(reference.Metadata.ClrType);

            var callCloneEntityMethod = Expression.Call(null, genericCloneEntityMethod, new Expression[] { referenceEntityEntry, cloneMapConstant });

            yield return Expression.Bind(reference.Metadata.PropertyInfo, callCloneEntityMethod);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> CreatePropertyBinding<TEntity>(ref EntityEntry entityEntry, ref ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        var entityEntryType = parameter.Type.GetProperty(nameof(EntityEntry.Entity), typeof(object));
        var entityProperty = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, entityEntryType);
        var convertedEntity = Expression.Convert(entityProperty, typeof(TEntity)); ;

        var result = entityEntry
            .Properties
            .Where(p => p.Metadata.IsShadowProperty() == false)
            .Select(p => Expression.Bind(p.Metadata.PropertyInfo, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(convertedEntity, p.Metadata.PropertyInfo)));

        return result;
    }
}

public class ConsoleDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("inmemory");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Owned<Address>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(person =>
        {
            person.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            person.Property(e => e.Name);
            person.OwnsOne(e => e.Address);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>(animal =>
        {
            animal.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            animal.HasDiscriminator();
            animal.Property(e => e.Name);
            animal.HasOne(e => e.Owner)
                .WithMany(e => e.Animals);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>(dog =>
        {
            dog.HasBaseType<Animal>();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>(cat =>
        {
            cat.HasBaseType<Animal>();
        });
    }
}
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Animal : Entity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public abstract class Entity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Entity<int>
{
    public Person()
    {
        //Animals = new HashSet<Animal>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```